# Where can I find documentation for Spark Data source API?

Tags: apache-spark

Is there any official documentation existing for Spark Data source API. I could only find sample/example implementation information from DataBricks tutorials.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? What part of Spark's DataSource API is not clear enough and would beg for more elaborate explanation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So there is not any official documentation of how to create your own custom datasource with spark because its in spark developer api. Still we have some good blogs you can check that may be they will be helpful. I mention some blogs here

http://sparkdatasourceapi.blogspot.nl/2016/10/spark-data-source-api-write-custom.html

https://michalsenkyr.github.io/2017/02/spark-sql_datasource

There are some example codes are also here pls check below

https://github.com/VishvendraRana/spark-custom-datasource

And if you want to check real project which is using spark data source api check apache carbondata

https://github.com/apache/carbondata